# Can not access https://forums.developer.ebay.com/

Tags: networking, ssl

Ebay developer programs says to ask in their forums if I have a question, but when I go to https://forums.developer.ebay.com/ I am met with the following screen below, so I clearly can't ask there.

I've asked several other people to see if the page loads for them, and it does not. They get the same screen. Is this a problem on ebay's end?

I hope I am not asking in the wrong place... I would ask on ebay's own forums if I could. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. The site https://forums.developer.ebay.com returns a `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` error.

Comment: I guess Ebay's developer services are down and they just have very lousy communication

Comment: Questions about websites are out of scope. The website isn’t functional

Answer (score 3):

Always use a test site to see if it's the site that's down or just you…

One example [there are many]

https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com

From which we get…

[image]